# Graphql upsert (create new if not exist, update if exist)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I have been trying to wrap my head around this, but haven't been able to.

**Short intro**
I have a Serverless Next.js app using Drupal graphql (through apollo) as datastore

**What I can do successfully so far**
I can GET_DRUPAL_USER and I can UPDATE_USER just fine separately.

**Problem**
I'm trying to see if there is a way to combine GET_DRUPAL_USER and UPDATE_USER conditionally.
In other words:if a user doesnt exist: create it (CREATE_USER). If it exists: update it with the new data. (UPDATE_USER)

**Code Snippet**
For simplicity I only show the relevant parts as to show how I structured my code. I can clean GET a user from Drupal just fine, but what I'm struggling with is the concept of waiting for the result of the GET_DRUPAL_USER and conditionally do another GraphQl CREATE_USER or UPDATE_USER.

**Current layout of my component**

```
export default function rsvpGigProcess ({ id, user,loading }) {
...
 const GET_DRUPAL_USER = gql`
 query($my_email:[String]){
    userQuery(filter: {conditions: [{field: "mail", value: $my_email, operator: EQUAL}]}) {
        entities {
          ... on User {
            uid
          }
        }
   }
 }
`
 ...

 const [getDrupalUser, { error, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DRUPAL_USER);

  const _getOrCreateUser = () => {
     getDrupalUser({
        variables: {
          my_email:"emailaddress@gmail.com"
        }
     })
  }


  ...

  return (
  <button onClick={() => _getOrCreateUser()}>
         Get or Create user
  </button>
  )
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?